# Creating an empty asp.net core project in vscode

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

In visual studio we can create an empty asp.net core project. Do we have anything like that in visual studio code, or we only have to create an asp.net core MVC with this command : `dotnet new mvc -o MyProjectName` ?

Answer (score 2):

In [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new) about `dotnet new` command, it lists the templates that come pre-installed with the .NET SDK.

And we can run `dotnet new --list` or `dotnet new -l` to see a list of all installed templates.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. We have to use : `dotnet new web` instead of `dotnet new mvc`. For more information we can write `dotnet new` in the command. This Show us more CLI and help to know how to create projects in visual studio code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative you can try. I know of no advantage for doing this except for the fun of it. One possible advantage is that we can customize anything during this process if we know what we need to do for the customization.

Create a folder for the project, of course. In it create a csproj file with the following; change the `TargetFramework` as appropriate.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Create an `appsettings.json` file with the following (note the `AllowedHosts`).

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Create an `appsettings.Development.json` file with the following (note there is no `AllowedHosts`). VS Code however will not allow use of the name `appsettings.Development.json`. A workaround is to (in VS Code) copy and paste the `appsettings.json`file then rename that. Be sure to remove the `AllowedHosts`.

```
{
    "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
      }
    }
  }
```

Outside of VS Code, create a `Properties` folder (VS Code says that `Properties` is not a valid folder name). Add a `launchSettings.json` file to the folder with the following. The ports can be customized.

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:28210",
      "sslPort": 44341
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "AspNetCoreEmpty": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7126;http://localhost:5126",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Create a `Program.cs` with the following.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

Go to the project directory in a terminal window and issue:

```
dotnet build
```

It should build. The project will essentially be the same as if it was built using `dotnet new web`.